# C# Threading Timer stopped after one initialization

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

My System.Threading.Timer stopped after initialization which only executes the OnTimedEvent once. What is the problem here? It should be expected to run the OnTimedEvent every second.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(OnTimedEvent), null, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: Do you store the `timer` variable somewhere so that Garbage Collection doesn't collect the `Timer` object it refers to?

Comment: The code you are showing doesn't do this

Comment: Show us the OnTimedEvent as well, just in case you are modifying the timer there

Comment: Using the code you provided, it's not possible to understand where the error is. Provide more code, please.